# Is it possible to design an ASP.NET website that doesn't PostBack enough?

Tags: asp.net, callback, postback

I'm bulding an ASP.NET website just to test my skills, and I'm using lots of callbacks that doesn't require a page refresh, and the URL doesn't change.  In this example, assume I'm bulding a web-based Outlook with a treeview, a grid, and a detail pane.

Is there a standard (published or assumed) that says I should postback, or even update my URL from time to time?

Comment: @John Saunders FYI: I had HTML5 as a tag since it's possible to update a url via a postback, or the proposed HTML5. Also, WCF is a technology I use to avoid postbacks. I'll leave the edits you made, but want you aware

Comment: it's good to know. Your tags still had nothing at all to do with your question. Tags are meant to categorize the question, not to list things that happen to be related to the question. If you were using HTML5 to do the update, or if your question was about using WCF to avoid postbacks, then those tags would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Standard* you are probably looking for is called usability. DHTML, Ajax, or whatever you want to call it is fine until it breaks the users expectation of browser behavior. When the back button fails to work, and users can't bookmark the page exactly as they expect, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an official standard, but you may want to check out Gmail to see a good example of how something similar was done.  The URL changes on the site much more often than the page refreshes.